# Configure Image asset shows error while adding icon in android studio,linux

Tags: android, android-studio, nosuchmethoderror, twelvemonkeys

I have just updated Android Studio to 3.5.3 in Linux. After that, I couldn't add image asset as it shows error -

> preview rendering error

The error screen is added below

[image]

In the previous version, it was working fine. Please, help

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi.canDecodeAs(Ljava/lang/Object;I)Z
    at com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.plugins.tiff.BigTIFFImageReaderSpi.canDecodeInput(BigTIFFImageReaderSpi.java:58)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$CanDecodeInputFilter.filter(ImageIO.java:567)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:834)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:828)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:519)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getImageReaders(ImageIO.java:646)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.TipUIUtil.read(TipUIUtil.java:254)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.TipUIUtil.updateImages(TipUIUtil.java:210)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.TipUIUtil.getTipText(TipUIUtil.java:126)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.TipUIUtil.openTipInBrowser(TipUIUtil.java:150)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.TipPanel.setTip(TipPanel.java:84)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.TipPanel.nextTip(TipPanel.java:107)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.TipDialog.initialize(TipDialog.java:55)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.TipDialog.<init>(TipDialog.java:46)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.TipDialog.createForProject(TipDialog.java:108)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.TipDialog.showForProject(TipDialog.java:95)
    at com.intellij.ide.TipOfTheDayStartupActivity.runImpl(TipOfTheDayStartupActivity.java:50)
    at com.intellij.ide.TipOfTheDayStartupActivity.lambda$runImpl$0(TipOfTheDayStartupActivity.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.commands.InvokeLaterCmd.lambda$run$0(InvokeLaterCmd.java:37)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:706)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:375)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

This is what I get while starting the Android Studio.

Comment: i couldn't find a solution. so i just uninstalled studio and again installed from ubuntu software's. and now it is working correctly. the current version which is available in the ubuntu software's is 3.5.2

Comment: Seems to be a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/MPS-30019) in IntelliJ (which Android Studio is based on). May be due to duplicate dependencies, but this isn't verified. Perhaps the old version was kept in the lib folder after you updated?